# Emacs find-file over SSH is too slow to connect

Tags: tramp, ssh

I am trying to connect to a remote server through SSH to edit some projects.

I do `C-x C-f` and then `/ssh:username:ip:`. It displays a password prompt. I type my password and press `RET`. It takes very long time to connect and even after that, it is barely usable. I can't really type any directory-file names because it takes ~20 seconds for each character to appear etc. And when I am finally able to type the path I want as in `/ssh:username:ip:/file/i/want`, it hangs up and does not open the file. Maybe it will at some point but it is so slow that I was never able to wait enough. Same issue when I try to use `dired` to open a remote directory as well, with `C-x C-d`. Of course, I am able to connect through ssh on bash just fine.

I tried some of the suggestions mentioned here like adding some stuff that mentioned in EmacsWiki which supposedly should help with slowness of tramp, using a fixed Projectile powerline etc. but none of them helped. What might be the cause?

I am using Emacs 29.0.50 and it is used as a GUI app run through WSL2 Debian on Windows.

### Additional Info

I set the tramp logging level to 6 and got the following logs.

```
12:41:12.920688 tramp-process-actions (6) # 

user@ip's password: 
Linux Kafa1500 5.10.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.46-4 (2021-08-03) 
x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free 
software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
You have new mail.
Last login: Thu Jan  6 12:40:07 2022 from 172.29.252.94
xrdb: Can't open display ''
Can't open display 
Can't open display 
[0;30m[45m 12:40:15 [0;35m[43m▶[0;30m[43m meguli 
[0;30m[43m│[0;30m[43m ╤ ip [0;33m[44m▶[0;30m[44m ~ 
[0;34m[49m▶
[0;30m[45m $ [0;35m[49m▶[0m 
12:41:12.920812 tramp-process-sentinel (5) # Sentinel called: ‘# 
<process *tramp/ssh user@ip*>’ ‘killed
’
12:41:12.922779 tramp-process-actions (1) # File error: Timeout 
reached, see buffer ‘*tramp/ssh user@ip*’ for details

user@ip's password: 
Linux Kafa1500 5.10.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.46-4 (2021-08-03) 
x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free 
software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
You have new mail.
Last login: Thu Jan  6 12:40:07 2022 from 172.29.252.94
xrdb: Can't open display ''
Can't open display 
Can't open display 
[0;30m[45m 12:40:15 [0;35m[43m▶[0;30m[43m meguli 
[0;30m[43m│[0;30m[43m ╤ ip [0;33m[44m▶[0;30m[44m ~ 
[0;34m[49m▶
[0;30m[45m $ [0;35m[49m▶[0m 
12:41:38.731775 tramp-process-actions (3) # Waiting for prompts 
from remote shell...failed
12:41:38.732061 tramp-maybe-open-connection (3) # Opening 
connection nil for user@ip using ssh...failed
```

It looks like it actually connects and opens the terminal but then receives a timeout. Upon further research, it seems like this might be due to TRAMP not recognizing fancy prompt on my remote shell, but I don't know a workaround for this.

Comment: Is emacs comparably slow when running with `-Q`?

Comment: No, it is pretty fast except for the case above, having the same slow SSH issue for `-Q` as well.

Comment: try **scp:** instead, it will be fast. as long there is only one hope. i.e. no ssh: over tunneling allowed with scp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, Tramp doesn't like your fancy prompt. The Tramp manual explains what to do, the FAQ section. In short, you shall add to your remote `.profile`

```
           [[ $TERM == "dumb" ]] && PS1='$ ' && return
```

If the shell on the remote host is `zsh`, you need to set

```
           [[ $TERM == "dumb" ]] && unsetopt zle && PS1='$ ' && return
```